# Can a find and replace script be run automatically in google sheets that will replace multiple values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I have a script that will run and replace instances of CHA with A only in column B. Where I want to go from here is to replace all of the following:

- CHA -> A
- CHB -> B
- CHC -> C
- CHD -> D
- PMA -> A
- PMB -> B
- PMC -> C 
   and if possible
- double space "  " -> single space " "

The script that I have will not change all instances if a cell contains more than one. For example a cell containing "CHA CHA" might only change to "A CHA", unless the script is run multiple times. Is there a way to loop the script and catch these? Is there a way to have 1 script change all the requested texts? Below is my current script and a link to a test google sheet. Any help or insight is greatly appreciated.

```js
    function onOpenCHA() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B");
      var to_replace = "CHA";
      var replace_with = "A";
      replaceInSheetCHA(sheet,range, to_replace, replace_with);
    }
    
    function replaceInSheetCHA(sheet, range, to_replace, replace_with) {
         //Confirm
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
      var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var data  = range.getValues();
        var oldValue="CHA";
        var newValue="A";
        var cellsChanged = 0;
        for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
          for (var item=0; item<data[row].length; item++) {
            oldValue = data[row][item];
            newValue = data[row][item].replace(to_replace, replace_with);
            if (oldValue!=newValue)
            {
              cellsChanged++;
              data[row][item] = newValue;
            }
          }
        }
        range.setValues(data);
        spread.toast(cellsChanged + " cells changed", "STATUS");
      }
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ox2CcQ6krih80V44HbG724XpIZKAp4BwkbHI2va-fvg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can change all instances of a string in a range with a `TextFinder`.*

#### Sample Code:

```js
function replace() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var colB = sheet.getRange("B1:B");
  
  var valsToChange = ["CHA", "CHB", "CHC", "CHD", "PMA", "PMB", "PMC", "  "];
  var changeToArr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", " "];
  
  valsToChange.forEach(function(v, i) {
    colB.createTextFinder(v).replaceAllWith(changeToArr[i]);
  });
}
```

**Rundown of this code:**

- Gets the sheet you want to replace the strings in
- Defines the strings you want to replace
- Defines the strings you want to appear
- Loops through each string in the range and replaces them all with its respective replacement string

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)